# NAudio - Playing back MIDI from Stream

Tags: c#, playback, midi, naudio

I'm making a game and using NAudio to play back sounds. I want to play a MIDI file for music looping in the background. Having searching for it in the documentation, found nothing.

How can I play a MIDI file from a stream?

And loop it?

Thanks.

Comment: unfortunately this is not a feature of NAudio. some more game development oriented audio libraries might offer better options here.

Comment: @MarkHeath Thanks for response. I'm playing the midi file with `mciSendString` from `winmm.dll`

Answer (score -1):

You can do it easily with [DryWetMIDI](https://github.com/melanchall/drywetmidi):

```
using Melanchall.DryWetMidi.Multimedia;
using Melanchall.DryWetMidi.Core;

// ...

var midiFile = MidiFile.Read("Background music.mid");
// or from stream:
// var midiFile = MidiFile.Read(stream);

var outputDevice = OutputDevice.GetByName("MIDI device to play with");
var playback = midiFile.GetPlayback(outputDevice);

playback.Loop = true;
playback.Start();
```

Read more about playback in [Playback](https://melanchall.github.io/drywetmidi/articles/playback/Overview.html) article of the library docs.